# Draw text or line on SurfaceViewRenderer in webRTC?

Tags: android, draw, webrtc-android

I am struggling to draw text or line on SurfaceViewRenderer. I am using below GitHub sample for WebRTC. https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC. Please anyone can help on this.